# single line alignment in textview

Tags: android, textview

I have one string `"name:Android\n Dateofbirth:23-05-1992"` and one Text view. I set it using:

```
textview.setText("name:Android\n Dateofbirth:23-05-1992")
```

Result is:

```
       name:Android
       Dateofbirth:23-05-1992
```

Expected result:

```
       name         :   Android
       Dateofbirth  :   23-05-1992
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Either you have to use 4 textviews or use HTML formatted string

Comment: Easiest way is 4 textviews.  YOu have 4 pieces of data you want displayed in a very specific format, that makes a lot more sense than using 1 string.

Comment: use table layout and string splitting

Comment: TextView isn't really the best view for this. You can set up 6 text views, 3 for each row. The left one has text left aligned, middle is just ":", and right one is left aligned as well. The two rows must be on top of each other. Other than that, you should use a table layout.

Comment: We only need 4, no need 6. ":" can move with the right path with some spaces. Easy.